# How to make a smooth seamless infinite HTML/CSS animation?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I've been trying to make a infinite seamless vertical scrolling line but fails with the restart of the animation that makes the whole page blink. Any clues where to go next?

This is made from trying examples and rewriting them but I am out of options.

Here's how far I've gotten yet: http://galle.ri-ga.se/ll/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #39B54A;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #ff0;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 1px 25px 20px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Courier;
}

h6 {
  background-color: #ff0;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 1px 25px 20px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Courier;
}

logo-slider {
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

logo-slider div {
  position: relative;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

logo-slider svg {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> galleri gasell &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;( ͡° ᴥ͡°)</h1><br>
<h6>coming soon</h6>
<logo-slider>
  <div class="hej2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 337.34">
<style>.a{fill:#eb008b;}</style>
<polygon class="a" points="375 0 0 197.34 0 337.34 375 140 375 0"/></svg>
  </div>

  <div class="hej2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 337.34">
<style>.a{fill:#eb008b;}</style>
<polygon class="a" points="375 0 0 197.34 0 337.34 375 140 375 0"/></svg>
  </div>

  <div class="hej2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 337.34">
<style>.a{fill:#eb008b;}</style>
<polygon class="a" points="375 0 0 197.34 0 337.34 375 140 375 0"/></svg>
  </div>
</logo-slider>
```

Comment: What have you tried ? can you provide some code ?

Comment: @Dhaifallah Added code in post.

Comment: @ZachJensz The mess is why I am here for. Thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this How you want it to look like ?

```css
*{
margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #39B54A;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #ff0;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 1px 25px 20px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Courier;
}

h6 {
  background-color: #ff0;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 1px 25px 20px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Courier;
}

logo-slider {
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

logo-slider div {
  position: relative;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
  
  width:100%;
   transform: rotate(105deg);
}

logo-slider svg {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> galleri gasell &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;( ͡° ᴥ͡°)</h1><br>
<h6>coming soon</h6>
<logo-slider>
  <div class="hej2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 337.34">
<style>.a{fill:#eb008b;}</style>
<polygon class="a" points="375 0 0 197.34 0 337.34 375 140 375 0"/></svg>
  </div>

  <div class="hej2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 337.34">
<style>.a{fill:#eb008b;}</style>
<polygon class="a" points="375 0 0 197.34 0 337.34 375 140 375 0"/></svg>
  </div>

  <div class="hej2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 337.34">
<style>.a{fill:#eb008b;}</style>
<polygon class="a" points="375 0 0 197.34 0 337.34 375 140 375 0"/></svg>
  </div>
</logo-slider>
```

Comment: That looks much better! Thanks! Is it the margin thing in the beginning you added and the rotate 105° thing that solved it?

Comment: You're welcome ! No, actually the problem was `z-index` within the `@keyframes marquee` you didn't need to add it again to the animation.

Comment: ah. I was in a hurry making these changes. So great that you found out what it was!